# MyBatis Mapper association reflected in java class

Tags: java, associations, mybatis

I wonder do one have to reflect the associated property in the class

If I use select with a join and then create a mapper as i.e.

```
<resultMap type="Company.Company" id="companyResult"  >
    <result column="id"    property="id" />
    <result column="name"  property="name" />    
    <association property="CompanyLevelId" resultMap="LevelMap" />
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="LevelMap"   type="Company.CompanyLevel"  >
    <id     column="CompanyLevelId"    property="CompanyLevelId" />
    <result column="Operator"         property="Operator" />
    <result column="Level"            property="level" />
</resultMap>
```

What would my Company class look like?
Do I have to create a a new class that includes the class Company level as an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Company class will have three fields, an integer id, a String name, and a CompanyLevel object called, in this case, CompanyLevelId.  The CompanyLevel class will also have three fields, CompanyLevelId, Operator, and level.

The association will convert the result of your join into a CompanyLevel object as defined by the LevelMap result map.

So your java class for Company should look like:

```
public class Company{
    int id;
    String name;
    CompanyLevel CompanyLevelId; //this name is defined by the 'property' attribute

    public Company(){
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

And CompanyLevel will look like:

```
public class CompanyLevel{
    int CompanyLevelId;  //once again defined by 'property' attribute
    String Operator;
    int level;

    public CompanyLevel(){
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

To make it clearer I would change the property name from CompanyLevelId to something like level for the Company class and id for the CompanyLevel class and specify a java type for the association.  That will make it look like this:

```
<resultMap type="Company.Company" id="companyResult"  >          
    <result column="id"    property="id" />          
    <result column="name"  property="name" />              
    <association property="level" resultMap="LevelMap" javaType="Company.Company" />          
</resultMap>          

<resultMap id="LevelMap"   type="Company.CompanyLevel"  >          
    <id     column="CompanyLevelId"    property="id" />          
    <result column="Operator"         property="operator" />          
    <result column="Level"            property="level" />          
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!
I did this but it would not work and now I discovered that in Netbeans if you refactor propertys with new name the xhtml file will not find the property and sins I did not get any debug info I could not see it. But now I delted propertys and added them again and it works better. This error is possible to reproduce.

Thanks again!!